# Convert this curl command to Python requests

Tags: python, api, curl, python-requests

**working curl command:**

```
curl -i -XPATCH "https://api.threatstream.com/api/v1/intelligence/"
  -H "Content-Type: application/json"
  -H "Authorization: apikey email@email.com:password"
  --data @C:\Users\ghossh6\indicators.json
```

**requests:**

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'apikey email@email.com:password',
}

data = open("C:/Users/ghossh6/indicators.json")
response = requests.patch('https://api.threatstream.com/api/v1/intelligence/', headers=headers, data=data)
```

**Response**

Currently, I only get 502 or 405 error codes. I have tried using json.loads() to load the file instead, without success.

Comment: Your Python looks correct to me. Setting up a test webserver locally, the `curl` command and your Python code generate approximately the same request (the `User-agent` is different, of course, and the Python request includes an `Accept-Encoding` header that isn't present when using `curl`, but otherwise they are identical).

Comment: One difference would be that requests encodes the file content as latin1 if you open it in text mode, try opning it in binary mode

Comment: It's always helpful if you can narrow down the _specific_ difference you don't know how to address before asking, and to focus the title on that difference. Otherwise, we could have 100 different questions all named "convert this curl command to python requests", but each asking how to get `requests` to implement a slightly different part of curl's behavior. Such a collection of questions would be of no use to anyone, because anyone with a 101st question would have no way to find out if any of the 100 that are already there already cover their problem.

Comment: A good place to start is using a packet sniffer to trace the specific requests -- https makes it a little trickier, but with both curl and requests you can generate a log with session keys that wireshark can use to decrypt the actual payload so you can see and compare the requests made by each. Or just pass `-v` to curl to tell it to dump its traffic, including headers; I believe `requests` has similar logging functionality available. (`--trace` is also useful, for getting curl's view of exactly what it's doing).

Comment: @mata opening the file in binary mode worked! Thanks so much!!!